# Collection cannot be null on SaveOrUpdate()

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, exception

I have a problem, when I try to save new User in database. My code:

```
if (!user.ValidateUser(username, password))
{
    using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    {
        User u = new User();
        u.Name = username;
        u.Email = string.Empty;
        u.Password = "123456";
        using (var transact = session.Transaction)
        {
            session.SaveOrUpdate(u); // I have an exception in this line
            transact.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> Collection cannot be null. Parameter name: c

How to save new user in database?

P.S. `session.Save(user1);` get me this exception too.

**Update:** User class

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.CurrentTestings = new HashSet<CurrentTesting>();
        this.ResultsSet = new HashSet<ResultTesting>();
    }

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CurrentTesting> CurrentTestings { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ResultTesting> ResultsSet { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the `User` class.

Comment: What do you create a new User instead of re-use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe class "User" has some references, for example:

```
class User
{
  IList<T> T;
}
```

Try to initialize this field with constractor:

```
class User
{
  public User
  {
    T = new List<T>();
  }
  IList<T> T;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case i needed to change the collection initzialize from Hashset to Hashedset.